# Is it safe to just write @user.save in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose i have a model User and a controller UsersController,

in my create actions, i can write

```
def create 
  @user  = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**or**

```
@user = User.new(uer_params)
if @user.save
  redirect_to users_path
else
  render :new
end
```

**Replicate above 2 actions for Update and destroy also**

My question is related to 2nd create action, 
Is is necessary to add `if else end`. what worse could happen i just have create actions like 1st one.

**Note:** **Please ignore the validations part for now.**

Just suppose I do not any validations.

What are the other possible conditions in which create/update/destroy will fail apart from validations and which one is the good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if User.create(user_params)
```

is always true. `create` returns on active reocrd object regardless whether it was successfully created or not. This is why we usually do:

```
@user = User.new(uer_params)
if @user.save
  redirect_to users_path
else
  render :new
end
```

Also note that we are ot redirecting to a new action. The reason is that we already has an `@user` variable, which 1) holds all the attributes entered by user 2) has all the validation errors attached to it. All we need to do is to render `:new` template and let Rails do its magic.

Note: If we ignore the validation, then there is no difference which option you will use. You don't need if/else statement neither as it will throw an exception if save fails for any other reason than validation (unless you have after/before_save hooks).

Comment: thanks for the answer, please check the updated question, i just want to know is it necessary to wite if else end , and also suppose i do not have any validations

Answer (score 2):

Given that you don't want to perform any validations or any checks on the status of the save, then there's no reason for the conditional. In fact, in that case there's also no reason for the `@user` instance variable. This is all you would need:

```
def create 
  User.create(user_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

The conditional is just to do different things based on the status of the save. The instance variable is only to pass the User object to the view. But if you're always doing a redirect then you can't utilize the instance variable anyway, so no need.

What's "right" here is up to the needs of your application. Do the minimum necessary until you have a problem and then fix it.

Comment: That's right... assuming the code is all correct, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

**Difference between `create` & `save` ?**

From the docs:

[**create**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/create)

> Tries to create a new record with the same scoped attributes defined
>   in the relation. Returns the initialized object if validation fails

[**save**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save)

> .... By default, save always run validations. If any of them fail the
>   action is cancelled and save returns false. However, if you supply
>   validate: false, validations are bypassed altogether.

**What about validations?**

Well,

1. **Create** will try saving and returns the initialized  object anyway (successful or failed save after validations)
2. **Save** will try saving and returns true for successful save and false otherwise

Note that you can skip validations by passing false to save

```
@user.save(false)
```

**So, what about Conditions?**

If you chose to skip validations, using **Create** or **Save(false)** then you don't need conditions, while if you need validations then you probably need to check how things went then give user some feedback, hence the conditions

Comment: thank for answer. my main theme of question is, what are other possible conditions in which it will fail apart from validations.

Comment: @RahulSingh Connection to the db lost, unexpected inconsistency in the db causing it to fail. There are a number of possible scenarios, there is a reason there is a usually check for a failed save.

Comment: @Iceman thank you, can you post it as an answer, also in such conditions, writing my code inside if else end saves me. or it will raise an exceptions.